# Picasso cache behaviour documentation

Tags: android, picasso

I'm struggling to find documentation beyond this nice website:

http://square.github.io/picasso/

I've used the documented lines, and it's working as far as getting the picture to where it's supposed to be.

My question is about the caching. I've got URLs that I know won't be changing. How can I tell Picasso to keep things in its disk cache so my app doesn't have to keep downloading the resource? It currently seems to use the cache occasionally, but it's definitely re-requesting too often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picasso is cachng by default (underlying OkHttp uses one). It may be issue that you lack permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Memory cache defaults seams ok. To customize disk cache you can use and alter insanely large disk cache here [PicassoBigCache](https://gist.github.com/fada21/10655652)